# The detailed view of the last item of a list build by TypoScript is always blank

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Here's the TypoScript code.

```
lib.membersList = CONTENT
lib.membersList{
table = tt_address
select{
    pidInList = {$membersStorageFolder}
    orderBy = zip, last_name
}

wrap = <div class="membersList">|</div>

renderObj = COA
renderObj{
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10{
        file = fileadmin/templates/ext/memberslist/templates/membersList.html

        variables{

            portrait = IMAGE
            portrait{
                file.import = uploads/pics/
                file.import {
                    field = image
                    listNum = 0
                }
                file.height = 105
                file.width = 105c

                stdWrap.typolink{
                    parameter = {$membersPageId}
                    additionalParams.dataWrap = &ts_addresslist[showUid]={field:uid}
                    #returnLast = url
                    # The cache hash is needed to display the right content, since we are not running as USER_INT
                    useCacheHash = 1

                }
            }

            lastName = TEXT
            lastName.field = last_name
            lastName.typolink{
                 parameter.data = TSFE:id
                 additionalParams.dataWrap = &ts_addresslist[showUid]={field:uid}
                 # The cache hash is needed to display the right content, since we are not running as USER_INT
                 useCacheHash = 1

             }

            firstName = TEXT
            firstName.field = first_name
            firstName.typolink{
                 parameter.data = TSFE:id
                 additionalParams.dataWrap = &ts_addresslist[showUid]={field:uid}
                 # The cache hash is needed to display the right content, since we are not running as USER_INT
                 useCacheHash = 1

             }

            title = TEXT
            title.field = title

            organisation = TEXT
            organisation.field = company

            country = TEXT
            country.field = country

            city = TEXT
            city.field = city
        }
    }

}


stdWrap.override.cObject = CONTENT

stdWrap.override.cObject{
    table = tt_address
    select {
      andWhere.data = GP:ts_addresslist|showUid
      # Make sure there is no SQL injection!
      andWhere.intval = 1
      andWhere.wrap = uid=|
      orderBy = last_name ASC
      pidInList = {$membersStorageFolder}
    }

    wrap = <div class="membersDetail">|</div>

    renderObj = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    renderObj{

       file = fileadmin/templates/ext/memberslist/templates/membersDetail.html

       variables{

           portrait = IMAGE
           portrait{
               file.import = uploads/pics/
               file.import {
                   field = image
                   listNum = 0
               }
               file.height = 105
               file.width = 105c
           }

           lastName = TEXT
           lastName.field = last_name

           firstName = TEXT
           firstName.field = first_name

           title = TEXT
           title.field = title

           organisation = TEXT
           organisation.field = company

           country = TEXT
           country.field = country

           city = TEXT
           city.field = city

           detail = TEXT
           detail.field = description
       }
    }

    renderObj.stdWrap.append = TEXT
    renderObj.stdWrap.append{
        value = << Back to list
        typolink.parameter = {$membersPageId}
    }
}

stdWrap.override.if {
        isTrue.data = GP:ts_addresslist|showUid
        isTrue.intval = 1
}
}
```

Everything is working fine. The list is displayed as it should. The detailed view also except for the last item. When I click on it, the detailed view displays a blank page. No information, as if the query fetched nothing.

Here are the templates, very simple though.
**membersList.html**

```
<section>
{portrait -> f:format.raw()}
<div class="memberDetail">
    <h1>{lastName -> f:format.raw()} {firstName -> f:format.raw()}</h1>

    <h2>{title} - {organisation}</h2>

    <h3>{country} - {city}</h3>
</div>
</section>
```

**membersDetail.html**

```
<section>
{portrait -> f:format.raw()}
<div class="memberDetail">
    <h1>{lastName} {firstName}</h1>

    <h2>{title} - {organisation}</h2>

    <h3>{country} - {city}</h3>
</div>
<div class="bio">
    {detail}
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Check if it depends on that item, or on the "last item" by deactivating the last item. TypoScript looks fine, so check your template or your records. F.e. item is restricted, hidden or so?

Comment: I added an item to see and it depends on the last item somehow as then the previous item appear and the new last one is not displayed. It is not deactivated, hidden or so. The template is the same for all the previous items. Could it be a weird loop effect coming from TypoScript? Would it be useful to post the templates too?

Comment: I do not expect an weird loop effect. Perhaps an HTML bug? Post the templates too. You allready checked the HTML-Source? Perhaps an HTML error/CSS Issue hides that content?

Comment: I edited my post, adding the two template files. They are very simple though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right so far. For debugging purpose add it directly to page object.

```
page.38388383 = CONTENT
page.38388383 {
  table = tt_address
  select{
    pidInList = {$membersStorageFolder}
    orderBy = zip, last_name
  }
  wrap = <div class="membersList">(|)</div>

  renderObj = COA
  renderObj{
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = uid
    10.wrap = (|),
  }
}
```

With this, you should get a comma separated list of all tt_address records without sideeffects. If that does not work, check on database level if everything is correct. Perhaps you some trouble with language, workspace or so...?

If this works like expected, you can replace your renderObj with this one and see what happens.

If expect that there is no crazy loop effect - but some CMS sideeffects (like missing rights, language, workspace version etc.).

Comment: The thing is I did have all the members in a list. The thing not working properly is the detailed view of the last item displayed on that list. But you gave me a good idea. I'll do it again on a blank page, without anything that could interfere and see what happens... Thanks.

Comment: seems that i did not get it yet. The list is ok, but the last link shows you an empty page. Did you clear the cache? What happens if you add &no_cache=1 to the url? What happens if you change the order? Is there a difference between link on last_name and potrait? ($membersPageId wrong?)